# How to code the larger images than div with css

Tags: language-agnostic

i want to place a larger image than box on my site design (look at the link for image), its a part of my site design. i wants to use css method. iam now using dreaweaver and i want to code these image, please help me.

- The size of white bg area is 737×323,(w×h) The size of yellow area is 275×323(w×h), 
  The size of fruit picture is 690×180. (w×h)

  **[Image link](http://img715.imageshack.us/i/page218.jpg/)**

Comment: You need to supply some context for this question. You say it is "a larger image than box on my site..." What does the box on your site look like? Can you modify it? One way to have something overflow the space available is to use negative offsets, but it's not clear if that's a valid solution until we see some context.

Comment: Dear friend, please refer to the image link on the question. On that link you can see that there is a white bg for the main box and a yellow content box and an fruit image larger than that content box. i want to place that image over than that content box, which image is larger. Please provide sufficient code and explanation, thanks in advance..

Comment: Ah, so the image is a mock-up of what you want. You don't want to actually use that image as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that should give you a starting point. The main trick is to use `position:absolute`. I recommend you [read about what that means](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp). Essentially, it lets you specify exact pixel coordinates of your page elements.

Note that the dimensions you give in your question are a little strange.You say the fruit picture is 690x180, for instance. But when I look at the image, it seems the fruit is basically square. Perhaps your image has a lot of transparent space? It is not clear without seeing the images themselves.

Also, on a real site you would probably want another nested `<div>` for the text itself, inside the yellow box.

Anyway, here is an example that just uses colored rectangles in the approximate arrangement your image shows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
.back {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:gray;
    width:700px;
    height:400px;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    text-align:right; /* just to make the text readable in this example */
}

.text {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:600px;
    height:300px;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    text-align:right; /* just to make the text readable in this example */
}

.fruit {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    width:300px;
    height:380px;
    left:10;
    top:10;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='back'>the background</div>
    <div class='text'>the yellow area</div>
    <div class='fruit'>put the fruit image here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are many other ways to do it, of course, depending on how you cut up your images.

Comment: sorry :( the size of fruit is really, 262×323 and size of yellow area is 720×190 and size of white bg is 775×323,  forgive me for providing incorrect measurements. But the trouble is cleared by the answer from j.w and iam really happy. :)